# Flurl PostUrlEncoded does GET instead of POST

Tags: c#, flurl

I must be missing something very obvious, but I can't tell what. I have a `DoLoginAsync` like so:

```
private async Task DoLoginAsync(bool force = false)
        {
            try
            {
                if (client.Cookies.ContainsKey("user_credentials") && !force)
                {
                    return;
                }
                var html = client.Request("login").GetStringAsync().Result;
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(html);
                var csrf_token = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta[@name='csrf-token']").First().GetAttributeValue("content", string.Empty);
                var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "user_session[email]", user },
                    { "user_session[password]", password },
                    { "authenticity_token", csrf_token }
                };
                var result = await client.Request("user_session").PostUrlEncodedAsync(values);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
```

When I run this code in a test with a breakpoint in the catch clause I get an exception

`Call failed with status code 404 (Not Found): GET http://www.whatever.com/user_session`

WTF? I'm expecting `PostUrlEncodedAsync` to do a POST, not a GET. Anybody have an idea why this can happen?

The Flurl client is instantiated as `client = new FlurlClient(BASE_URL).EnableCookies();`

**UPDATE**

Tried the following test which fails with the same exception

```
[TestMethod]
        public async Task TheTest()
        {
            var message = "";
            try
            {
                var client = new FlurlClient("http://www.slimmemeterportal.nl/").EnableCookies();
                var html = await client.Request("login").GetStringAsync();
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(html);
                var csrf_token = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta[@name='csrf-token']").First().GetAttributeValue("content", string.Empty);
                var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "user_session[email]", "******" },
                    { "user_session[password]", "******" },
                    { "commit", "inloggen" }, // Not sure if this is actually needed, but it is in the website's request parameters.
                    { "authenticity_token", csrf_token }
                };
                var result = await client.Request("user_session").PostUrlEncodedAsync(values);
            }
            catch (FlurlHttpException ex)
            {
                message = ex.Message;
            }
            Assert.AreEqual("Call failed with status code 404 (Not Found): POST http://www.slimmemeterportal.nl/user_session", message);
        }
```

Comment: I can't repro this. This tests passes: https://gist.github.com/tmenier/3417dcdf6ef0dfc6d0480ae778065b72. Are you seeing this every single time or occasionally in a high concurrency scenario?

Comment: @ToddMenier, it's consistent. It happens always.

Comment: Probably not related, but don't block here: `client.Request("login").GetStringAsync().Result`. Use `await client.Request("login").GetStringAsync()` instead.

Comment: What version of Flurl.Http are you using?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It's some testing code. But good point anyway

Comment: I'm using 2.8.0, installed via NuGet. Project is .NET core 2.1

Comment: 2.8.0 is probably Flurl, not [Flurl.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/). They're versioned separately. Make sure you're on the latest version of Flurl.Http. Also try running my gist in your project.

Comment: Flurl.Http is 2.4.0. Your test passes on my system as well. I'm going to try and refactor a bit to be closer to your test.

Comment: I've added a test, same result. I don't see ant fundamental differences with your test?

Comment: With your test I'm failing earlier: "Call failed. An error occurred while sending the request. GET http://www.slimmemeterportal.nl/login". Inner exception: "SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". When I switch to Google URLs, it's still behaving as expected. Something's off here. Your posted code is _exactly_ what's running? You're certain that the first GET is to `/login` and the error refers to `GET .../user_session`? If so, I'm completely baffled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179758/discussion-between-hintham-and-todd-menier).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mystery solved: As it turns out after some debugging with Wireshark, the website was returning HTTP status code 301. As explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) the default action is to follow the URI in the response's location header using a GET even if the original request was a POST.

Comment: Ah..it redirected. In hindsight I can't believe I didn't think of that. Glad you solved it :)